# Rails chinese locale invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, localization

I'm localizing a Rails 3.2 - Ruby 1.9.3 app in traditional chinese.
Everything works fine in english but in chinese I get **invalid byte sequence in UTF-8.**

From my understanding Rails should work out of the box with chinese (not latin) localization. Am I missing anything?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace or a more complete error to show us ?

Comment: Have you added the magic comment at the beginning of the file? And, is there a reason you need to stick to Ruby 1.9.3? In Ruby 2.0, you do not need to worry about that kind of stuff. UTF-8 works right out of the box.

Comment: Here all the error message I got (not much more) Error is on line 3:


ompleted 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

ActionView::Template::Error (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8):
    1: <%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
    2:  <div class="login-fields">
    3:   <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="<%=t "email"%>" value ="<%= params[:email] %>" class="span8 login-field">
    4:

Comment: This the beginning of my zh-TW file:


# Sample localization file for Traditional Chinese (Taiwan). Add more files in this directory for other locales.
# See https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails%2Flocale for starting points.

zh-TW:

Comment: The app is running already in 1.9.3 and right now I don't have time to update it.  Thanks

Comment: Maybe youve used some non-utf-8 chars in your code? If you did then try out https://github.com/m-ryan/magic_encoding